# Rounding in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

So I've been tackling this rounding issue for the past month.  I like to think I am competent but this problem has me rethinking my entire existence.

So here it is.

I have a volume and a rate.

Line 1 = 410496.15 X .044370 = 18213.89

Line 2 = 7146.09 X .043753 = 312.67

Because of rounding I get 18526.55 for the total instead of 18526.56 which is what I want.
Problem is if I round to the 2nd place line 2's total show 312.66 because its not rounding .665 up.

Basically they want me to round to the 4th place but display 2 digits. i.e 4.1545 = 4.16   and 4.1544 = 4.15

Am I making sense?  Because I'm beginning to question reality here.

Comment: Thats a whole new rule of rounding, not as all world rounds, it is not impossible, you just have to code it via vba

Comment: "they want me to" - if this is really what "they" want, tell "them" to go back to school.

Comment: 4.1545 is closer to 4.15 than to 4.16 - that's how rounding works. The thing you are trying to do is an utter nonsense.

Comment: trust me i'm frustrated as all heck.  i've been back and forth with them for a month just on this rounding issue.  VBA is out of the question unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for your amusing description of a frustrating problem. At least you've still got your sense of humor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
=ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(value, 4), 3), 2)
```

You can't display this (wrong) rounding result but keep the right number without some programming. You can have two columns however with these two different numbers...

The "right" way of working with data is never rounding anything at all. You never need to - you can always display 2 decimal places for convenience keeping the precise number behind the scenes...

Comment: Thank you so much this totally worked.  freaking hate accountants